# Replace Section of String Rather than Character Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm just learning about regular expressions and I am trying to figure out how to do a string substitution for a collection of characters in a string rather than a substitution for each character (which is all I can get to happen thus far.

Lets say I have a string called original string:

```
original_string = "(cats && dogs) || (cows && chickens)"
```

I want to replace each word in the string with the string "test."  My desired result would look like:

```
new_string = "(test && test) || (test && test)"
```

So far, my code looks like:

```
replacement = "test" 
original_string = "(cats && dogs) || (cows && chickens)"
new_string = re.sub(r'[^(,^),^&,^|]', replacement, original_string)
```

But this causes each character in cats, dogs, cows and chickens to be replaced with "test".  So the result looks like:

```
 (testtesttesttesttest&&testtesttesttesttest)test||test(testtesttesttesttest&&testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest)
```

How can I use a regex to get my desired result?

Comment: also note you shouldn't comma-separate the characters in the `[]`. e.g. it should be `[abc]`, not `[a,b,c]`; `[^(^)^&^|]`, not what you have there.

Comment: Are you trying to do something with C++ (or similar) code?

Comment: I'm creating a sequel statement based on user input.

Comment: note that ^ at the begining of a character class means *not the following characters*, but at an another place it is seen as literal. As you can see vox populi vox dei isn't always a good advice in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simpler regex like:

```
replacement = "test" 
original_string = "(cats && dogs) || (cows && chickens)"
new_string = re.sub(r'[a-z]+', replacement, original_string)
```

`[a-z]+` means an alphabet appearing more than 1 time.

Though, keeping your original regex as much as possible, I would use this:

```
replacement = "test" 
original_string = "(cats && dogs) || (cows && chickens)"
new_string = re.sub(r'[^()|& ]+', replacement, original_string)
```

You don't need to repeat the `^`.